# A simple discrete math riddle

Tags: discrete-mathematics, puzzle

Let $\mathbb{P}$ be a set of integers. Let $\mathbb{N}$ be the number of the elements in $\mathbb{P}$. Prove that there must be a subset of $\mathbb{P}$ that it's sum is divided by $\mathbb{N}$.
Any idea?

Comment: What? Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: It should, in any set of $p$ integers, there exists a subset whose sum divisible by $p$.

Comment: @Arthur, thanks. Yes, set, and P means "the number of elements in P".

Comment: You're using P for the set, as well as the number of elements in P? There are 25 other letters available, you know....

Comment: @T.Bongers : Thanks, edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the integers be $a_1, a_2,\dots,a_N$.

Now, consider the sums 
$$\begin{align}
S_1&=a_1\\ 
S_2&=a_1+a_2\\
S_3&=a_1+a_2+a_3\\
\vdots\\
S_k&=a_1+a_2+\dots+a_k\\
\vdots\\
S_N&=a_1+a_2+\dots a_N
\end{align}$$

Now, if someone of $S_k$ is $0\pmod N$ then we are done.

If none of then is $0\pmod N$, then all the $S_i$'s can be $1,2,\dots,N-1\pmod N$.
But as there are there are $N$ $S_i$'s, there must be some $1\le j\le k\le N$ such that $$S_j\equiv S_k\pmod N\\\implies a_{j+1}+a_{j+2}+\dots+a_k\equiv 0\pmod N$$

Thus we have found $\{a_{j+1},\dots,a_k\}$ as the subset of $P$, whose sum of elements is divisible by $N$.

Comment: I didn't understand why if Sj≡Sk(modN) then the subset of aj+1+aj+2+⋯+ak≡0(modN). Can you please explain? Thanks.

Comment: @auto_ptr, $S_j=a_1+a_2+\dots a_j$ and $S_k=a_1+a_2+\dots+a_k$.